# Why are the type definitions for 'Iterable', 'Set', 'Map' etc. missing when I attempt to ng build my Angular 11 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I'm relatively new to Angular and the node ecosystem, so this might be a simple oversight.

**The problem**

I have an Angular 11 project in Visual Studio 2019 which is configured to use Typescript 4. Running this project through Visual Studio results in a 404 page, with the message "Cannot GET /". Attempting to build it through the command line with ng build results in a huge number of errors, with the gist being that several types cannot be found. These include Iterable, Set and Map. E.g.:

`Error: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:41:84 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

This message also appears many times, despite the option being set to es2017 (es2015 also results in the same errors, though):

`` Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later. ``

I've grepped for "Iterable" in my `node_modules/@types` folder, but have not found a definition for it, despite it being referenced in several places. *It's possible I'm missing a types package, but I don't know how to find out which one, if so.*

**Update**

This issue seems to be caused by referencing the following type definitions at the top of one of my services:

```
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts" />
```

Removing these references allows the project to build, but results in a mess of error highlights in Visual Studio for all the missing definitions. Not ideal. Alternatively, adding `"skipLibCheck": true,` to my tsconfig.json allows the application to build for now, but isn't a long term solution.

**What I've tried**

- I've updated Node.js, NPM, Angular CLI and all of the packages in my application.
- I've ensured that my package.json contains the newest version of @types/node
- I've made sure that my tsconfig.json is targeting es2015, and the lib compiler options contains "es2017" and "dom"
- I've checked that these are actually the files being used during the build process (inserting nonsense into them gets flagged up during an ng build.)
- I've deleted the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file, then reinstalled all packages with npm install

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental":  true, 
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "echo fix && ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run MyApp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.5.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.2",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyApp:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyApp",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing from `rxjs`? is it like `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` (rather than importing from `rxjs/internal/...`)

Comment: Like the first example - `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: After digging a little more, it seems like it wasn't `Observable` which was the issue, it was actually down to adding references to the top of my service:

```///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts" />```

Removing these allows the application to build, but then I get a whole bunch of intellisense errors in VS highlighting missing types. Alternatively, adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to my tsconfig also allows it to build, but I can't keep that in the long term.

Comment: Try changing target to es2019

Comment: Ahh I see, I'm not 100% sure but I have never needed to use `///` directives for this kind of thing. Sounds like some VS specific thing where it is not respecting your `tsconfig` settings or not finding the specific type libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue - there were two parts to the problem.

Firstly, I shouldn't have needed the triple-slash directive references in my .ts file. According to the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), these reference statements should only be used in typescript definition files - *"Use these directives only when you’re authoring a d.ts file by hand."*

```
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts" />
```

Secondly, I shouldn't have been seeing errors in my source files without these directives. The missing references were because of **ReSharper** not being able to find the definitions. I disabled the extension, and ordinary intellisense worked perfectly.

I've yet to figure out why exactly ReSharper was struggling to find, or read, the type definitions, but at least I can now continue work on the project. I'll post an update if I get resharper to behave.